# Jquery Ajax Call Rest API response is 200 but it throwing error

Tags: jquery, spring-boot, rest

Setup : Spring boot Rest API - Response `List<Object>`

Front End: Html with jQuery: Ajax call

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getcall")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Ratio> getCall(@RequestParam("date") String date, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
        
        return nseCache.getRatio(date);
    }
```

HTML Call:

```
function getall(){
debugger;
 $.ajax({ 
cache: false,

contentType: "application/javascript",
   url: "http://localhost:8080/jsonparser/getcall?date=14-Jan-2021",
  type: 'GET',
    headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'}, 
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(data){
        console.log("Success"+data);
        
    },
     error: function(data){
     debugger;
        console.log("error "+data);
    },
     failure: function(data){
        console.log("Failure"+data);
    }
});
}
```

Debugged on the Spring web application side:
Response is getting passed.

I tried to use the same API on PHP application and it is successfully fetched.
But due to limitation, I cannot use something else than jQuery.

Console output:

[image: Debug output]

Comment: What is dataType: 'jsonp',?

Comment: The `dataType` should be `json`.